# prevent gaps in MySQL id field

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with an auto incremement id field.  When I delete a row and then insert a new row, The id of the row I deleted is skipped and the new gets an id of one greater than the previous row.  Is there any way I can prevent this?  I would like the new row to just replace the old one.  Is there an important reason why this happens that I am missing?

Comment: You're trying to dig holes in a minefield here. The risk is concurrency bugs, the exact nature of which will depend on your application. Auto-increment ids are practically free (sure they can overflow but let's set that aside for the moment). Just accept that there will be gaps in the sequence and move on.

Comment: Basically, what you're asking to do is to have 2 records share the same primary key; one record that was just created and another record that was deleted perhaps only moments ago. Imagine a user of your website opened a page referencing the deleted record moments before it was deleted and the new record created. Imagine this user then submits an update to the deleted record. What should happen next in a properly designed application is that the update fails because the record has been deleted. Instead what happens is the new record is updated with the deleted record's data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of an autoincrement field is that every new row inserted is guaranteed to get a unique value.  If you want to keep the old value then you must UPDATE the row instead of replacing it.  If your design requires that autoincrement column values be contiguous then you will have to manage that yourself.

Comment: No, I used the word "replace" in the sense of delete the original and add a new row.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL auto-increment function NEVER goes backward unless you force it to.  And for a good reason.  What if there was stray references to the missing records (logs, tables, etc...)?

You can force it by using this command:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

Or, if you need to do it as part of the query:

```
LOCK TABLES tbl WRITE;
SELECT @id := MAX(id) FROM tbl;
INSERT INTO tbl SET id=@id, ...;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

If you are using InnoDB, you could do this in a transaction instead...

Better to leave it be, however.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I don't know the exact reason.

AFAIK you can't avoid that behavior unless you `TRUNCATE` the table or explicitly specify the id.